# Printf() after fork() and conditional being printed only once?

Tags: linux, fork

So I am trying to learn the fork() call, I am honestly confused on how this child process and parent process works. Here is part of the code:

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        value = ChildProcess(value);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
        value = ParentProcess(value);
    }

    printf("\nThe value is %d",value);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output should give me parent value and child value, and since there is no wait() call either parent value or child value can be printed first. But what I am confused is, why does the printf statement only being printed once?? Shouldn't it being printed twice since the fork call basically created a duplicated program??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you return from the child process after calling ChildProcess, so don't go through the printf